# PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected

Tags: system-installation

I just bought an Asus X556U laptop.  I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.10, but when it's booting, I get this message:

```
PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5 (Receiver ID)
device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00000000
```

I saw some people have the same problem, but they all have an already installed OS. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you install Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi Kaz! No i cant, it repeats the error over and over again and it never gets to the desktop.

Comment: Try to boot with the command line option `pcie_aspm=off`. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) for a how-to. If you're using the GRUB-based bootloader, just hit the `E` key on the "Try Ubuntu" option, and add that after `quiet splash`.

Comment: @KazWolfe it worked!!!! Tjanks a lot!!!

Comment: after off leave a space before --- (it is critical)